# two different hash values for same string

Tags: c++, cryptoapi

I need to compare hash values of two strings. 
I use string "template" for testing.
But I got different hash values for this string so it is always not the same.
I use CryptoApi and MD4

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::hash_map<int,int> table;
    HCRYPTPROV hProv1,hProv2;
    BYTE *pbBuffer1=(BYTE*)"template";//data to hash
    DWORD dwBufferLen1=strlen((char*)pbBuffer1)+1;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash1,hHash2;
    //first hash
    CryptAcquireContext(&hProv1,NULL,NULL,PROV_RSA_AES,0);
    CryptCreateHash(hProv1,CALG_MD4,0,0,&hHash1);
    CryptHashData(hHash1,pbBuffer1,dwBufferLen1,0);
    /*---------*/
    BYTE *pbBuffer2=(BYTE*)"template";//data to hash
    DWORD dwBufferLen2=strlen((char*)pbBuffer2)+1;
    //second hash
    CryptAcquireContext(&hProv2,NULL,NULL,PROV_RSA_AES,0);  
    CryptCreateHash(hProv2,CALG_MD4,0,0,&hHash2);
    CryptHashData(hHash2,pbBuffer2,dwBufferLen2,0);
    if (hHash1==hHash2)
        printf("The Same\n");
    else printf("Not same\n");
    /*---------*/
    std::cout<<hHash1<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<hHash2<<std::endl;
    if (hProv1)
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv1,0);
    if (hProv2)
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv2,0);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

For example hash value in hHash1

```
691136
```

Hash value in hHash2

```
691216
```

Comment: C tag replaced with c++. There is no `::` in C.

Comment: Did you step through it with a debugger? Two strings always produce the same hash, so something must be different about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers have noted, `hHash1` and `hHash2` are opaque handles — comparing them is pointless, as that's akin to comparing the addresses of two different objects that have the same value.

Use [`CryptGetHashParam`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the hash values and compare those instead:

> The `CryptGetHashParam` function retrieves data that governs the operations of a hash object. **The actual hash value can be retrieved by using this function.**

Answer (score 5):

`HCRPTHASH` is a `ULONG_PTR` typedef, as per [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That means it's a pointer:

> The `HCRYPTHASH` data type is used to represent *handles* to hash objects. These handles indicate to the CSP module which hash is being used in a particular operation. The CSP module does not enable direct manipulation of the hash values. Instead, the user manipulates the hash values through the hash handle.
>
> `typedef ULONG_PTR HCRYPTHASH;`

Comparing pointers with `==` is about as productive as nailing jelly (or jello to US citizens) to a tree, or trying to train a cat :-)

The values you're seeing as your "hashes" are actually the pointers, 80 bytes apart (since they are pointers to two different memory blocks).

In order to get the *actual hash* from the handle, you need something like the following, which prints the hex digits:

```
CHAR hexDigits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
BYTE md4Hash[MD4LEN];
DWORD cbHash = MD4LEN;
if (CryptGetHashParam (hHash1, HP_HASHVAL, md4Hash, &cbHash, 0)) {
    printf("MD4 hash is: ");
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < cbHash; i++) {
        printf ("%c%c", hexDigits[md4Hash[i] >> 4], hexDigits[md4Hash[i] & 0xf]);
    }
    printf("\n");
} else {
    DWORD dwStatus = GetLastError();
    printf ("CryptGetHashParam failed with code %d\n", dwStatus); 
}
```

For comparing the two hash values, you can do:

```
BYTE md4Hash1[MD4LEN], md4Hash2[MD4LEN];
DWORD cbHash1 = MD4LEN, cbHash2 = MD4LEN;

CryptGetHashParam (hHash1, HP_HASHVAL, md4Hash1, &cbHash1, 0);
CryptGetHashParam (hHash2, HP_HASHVAL, md4Hash2, &cbHash2, 0);

if ((cbHash1 == cbHash2) &&
    (memcmp (md4Hash1, md4Hash2, cbHash1) == 0))
{
    // they are equal.
}
```

Comment: I've done like this. I call CryptGetHashParam and put bytes into array for `hHash1` and `hHash2` and then compare it with `memcmp` and it seems working correctly.

Comment: @Артём, that's basically where I ended up after a search - see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

hHash1 and hHash2 are not the hash codes, but handles.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379908(v=vs.85).aspx